# Modify a substring matched by regex and place it back

Tags: r, regex

I have an arbitrary string, say "1a2 2a1 3a2 10a5" I want to do an arbitrary mathematical operation, say doubling,  to some of the numbers, say anything followed by an "a".

I can extract the numbers I want with relative ease

```
string = "1a2 2a1 3a2 10a5"
numbers = stringr::str_extract_all(string,'[0-9]+(?=a)')[[1]]
```

and obviously, doubling them is trivial

```
numbers = 2*(as.integer(numbers))
```

But I am having problems with placing the new results in their old positions. To get the output "2a2 4a1 6a2 20a5". I feel like there should be a single function that accomplishes this but all I can think of is recording the original indexes of the matches using `gregexpr` and manually placing the new results in the coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `str_replace_all` from `stringr` to capture numbers followed by `"a"` and then multiply them by 2 in their callback function.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(string, "\\d+(?=a)", function(m) as.integer(m) * 2)
#[1] "2a2 4a1 6a2 20a5"
```

Comment: Neat (+1). I was fumbling around with `str_split`.

Answer (score 3):

`gsubfn` is like `gsub` except that the second argument can be a string, function (possibly expressed in formula notation), a list or a proto object.  If it is a function the capture groups are input into it and the match is replaced with the output of the function.

```
library(gsubfn)
string <- "1a2 2a1 3a2 10a5"

gsubfn("(\\d+)(?=a)", ~ 2L * as.integer(..1), string)
## [1] "2a2 4a1 6a2 20a5"
```

This variation also works. `backref=0` says input the match into the function rather than the the capture groups.

```
gsubfn("\\d+(?=a)", ~ 2 * as.integer(x), string, backref = 0)
```